# Working with jQuery in Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I wrote a simple jQuery function that controls the click event of a mobile nav bar. However, I can't seem to get it to work properly. Whenever I click on the nav bar, I can see the menu shows up for half of a sec and then disappears. I've done some research online and it looks like this has to do with Rails 5 turbolinks. Since I'm quite new to rails and jQuery, I'm not quite sure how to fix the issue.

Below is my jquery code in the application.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#mobile").on("click", function(){

      $(".mobile_nav").toggleClass("open");

    });
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
<nav class="mobile_nav">
  <%= link_to"Blog", posts_path %>
  <%= link_to"About", about_path %>
  <%= link_to"Contact", new_contact_path %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  .mobile_nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobile_nav.open {
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: can you try modifying your CSS as : `.mobile_nav.open` i.e. remove space between `.mobile_nav` and `.open`

Comment: oh yeah, that was a mistake, I fixed it. But it still doesn't fix the issue tho

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrapping your js function in a document.ready call you should try the following since turbolinks doesn't re-render the whole page but instead tries to act like a partial page load:

```
$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   $("#mobile").on("click", function(){
      $(".mobile_nav").toggleClass("open");
   });
})
```

The turbolinks on page load is what will fire everytime a view is changed.